# Create and use Fulltext Index in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I want to create and use a fulltext index within a single procedure. For example:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[dbp_PCL_to_Demo_Matching_Mason] AS

--IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Medicaid_State_Claims'))
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Medicaid_State_Claims(Scrubbed_Account_Number)
      KEY INDEX nci_Seq_No;

select * from dbo.Medicaid_State_Claims
  where CONTAINS(Scrubbed_Account_Number, 'blahblah');
```

However, this fails with the error message:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'dbo.Medicaid_State_Claims' because it is not full-text indexed.

Uncommenting the "IF NOT EXISTS" condition makes no difference. However, if the index already exists and I uncomment that line and create the stored procedure, it works. But I'd rather not create it ahead of time, I want to create it within the stored procedure. How can I create the fulltext index and use it in the same stored procedure?

Comment: Full-text indexes take time to populate, so go ahead, create it ahead of time.  Otherwise you would have to put a loop in to say "wait until full-text index has finished populating" like [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69366/full-text-catalog-not-populating), but that's genuinely a bad idea for a production system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can, at least not within the same proc.

Stored procs are compiled before running, so that command is going to be checked for validity before it executes.

Full text is an entirely separate executable, and while you can certainly issue SQL commands that create a new full text index, or initiate a rebuild of one, or whatever, those commands aren't going to work like normal SQL commands (they can't be within an ATOMic transaction, they can't possibly roll back, etc.).

This means that just because the `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX` statement succeeds, that *doesn't guarantee the index is populated and/or useful*.

It's like issuing a `msdb.dbo.sp_start_job` to run a SQL agent job. The statement finishes quickly and returns control, but the agent could very well still be running (for a very long time).

Maybe you can trick it by calling separate stored procs, one that creates the full text index and kicks off a full build, and then another that checks the status of that build and loops till it is complete, before calling a proc that runs the query?

It seems likely to me that you will return a value faster by doing a normal `WHERE Scrubbed_Account_Number LIKE '%blahblah%'`, even though that will do a full table scan.

In fact, I guarantee that will be faster, since it will have to do a full table scan to build the full text index.

Comment: One word.  Dynamic SQL.  Ok, two-words.  But you get the picture.

Comment: Perhaps that would work, but see my edits, I can't imagine what he's trying is a good idea.

Comment: Agreed 100%, sounds like an A|B problem to me.

Comment: No, a `LIKE %text%` statement is far slower. I have tried and measured it. The problem is that I have two tables of data, each contain data from different sources. In the first table there is an account number, in the second table there is a string that may or may not contain an account number from the first table. I need to join them where the account number is in that larger string. Simple describe, slow to run when we're talking about millions of records. I wasn't aware that the fulltext index building was an asynchronous process, so this is helpful.

Comment: @MaxVernon It's not exactly an A|B problem. I've got an issue to solve, and I'm trying several different ways to find the best approach. I'm dealing with literally 5,000 databases, rewriting a complex matching process to join data from two separate sources that isn't guaranteed to be formatted perfectly since it's provided by customers and it would take them too much time to clean up millions of records before giving them to us. It's a complex thing requiring complex solutions, and I'm trying to keep it as simple as I can to combat that.

Comment: @mason have you considered looking outside of SQL Server? Elasticsearch is great for stuff like this, though it may not meet your need for complexity.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik yes. thanks for suggestion but that would change up current architecture too much. Eventually yes, it's a good idea.

Comment: @mason - so why do you need to setup full text *inside the stored proc*?  Can't you simply setup full text indexing ahead of time, then query the index as needed?  You haven't identified the requirement for creating the index programmatically.  By the way, I've worked on instances containing up to 10,000 databases; I feel your pain.

Comment: @MaxVernon I was trying to avoid it because it's an insert heavy table. Plus our DBA likes the idea of creating indexes where they're intended to be used, so long as index creation doesn't take too long. But anyways, I am now doing precisely what you said.

Comment: @mason Creating an index immediately before a query, and dropping it immediately afterwards seems... unusual, to say the least.

Comment: @BradC Not in this application. It's all throughout the code for normal indexes. Some of our stored procedures have logic that takes hours to run. Spending a couple minutes to create an index or two at the start of the procedure is worth it, and keeps inserts snappy during data insertion. I just assumed fulltext indexes worked like regular indexes as far as creation/removal but I was wrong.

Comment: I can see that in a very high-activity environment, with rarely run, huge queries/reports. Still not a typical use case.

Comment: You just described our environment. No, we're not typical.